# Access from View an ID from a list inside array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following structure:

```
public class MyType 
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

public class MyViewData : ObjetoViewModel
{
    public List<MyType>[] listParams { get; set; }
}
```

With that, I have loaded 5 lists of type `MyType` inside `listParams` array.

I'm trying to access the first `id` of the first list into my view and I'm not having any success. Im trying somthing like:

```
<%: Html.Label(Model.listParams[0]. ???? )%></td>
```

But I can't reach the value

Comment: What do you mean you can't reach the value? What happens? Why are you using `Html.Label` if you're just trying to access the value of a property? I'm not clear on what's going on here.

Comment: @AntP I dont know the way to get the value of field ID since its a list inside an array. Is there any other way to show the user the value I want if not from label ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print out element `y` of the list at array element `x` you just need the following:

```
<%: Model.lstParams[x][y].id %>
```

`Html.LabelFor` is for generating text labels that (by default) display the *name* of the property represented by the input, where the input would be an expression representing the property, *not* the value of a property, which is what you're trying to produce.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you want to use the Html.Label helper is because it generates the label that matches your property name for example.

If you had a single `MyType` as your model it would do this:

`<label for="id">id</label>`

`<input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="Some value"/>`

By using an array you're kind of losing that benefit, you can still make it work if you need to though. If you're trying to post the data back and that's why you want it to work you can.

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.lstParams; i++) { %>    
  <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.lstParams[i].id) %>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lstParams[i].name) %>    
<% } %>
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to produce a label at all. He wants to access the value.